# How do I reference files in the same folder html

Tags: html, css, file

I am making a webpage, with 2 files so far (not including the CSS). One is the home page, and one is the login. I want the user to be able to cycle through these pages when they want.

This is the code for my main (index) page here:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="logo"><img src="images/awlogo.png" height="50px"></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://w41k3r.com/login/?redirect=https://w41k3r.com/">Walkers</a></li>
        <li class="user"><a href="/contact.html">Login</a></li>
        <li class="user"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
</div>
```

(the other file is called conact)
Whenever I click the button on the website it shows page not found. The 2 pages are in the same folder

Comment: Typo?  You're navigating to `/contact.html` (page is in the site root) instead of `contact.html` (page is in the "current folder").

Comment: You've misspelled "contact" as "conact" in your question text. I don't know if that is intentional (and part of the issue) or not. Also, if index.html and contact.html are in the same folder, they should have the same prefix before the file name (i.e., `href="index.html"` and `href="contact.html"` OR `href="/index.html"` and `href="/contact.html"`),

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to write `./contact.html` instead of `/contact.html` in your link.

Here is the updated code:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="logo"><img src="images/awlogo.png" height="50px"></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://w41k3r.com/login/?redirect=https://w41k3r.com/">Walkers</a></li>
        <li class="user"><a href="./contact.html">Login</a></li>
        <li class="user"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
</div>
```